# What do all these numbers mean in the names of ecma-262, ecma-402, tc-39?

Tags: ecma

I just visited an [official github page](https://github.com/tc39) of TC39 and noticed that some of the names end with numbers, for example:

- TC39
- ecma-262
- ecma-402

Where do these numbers come from? Why not TC47, ecma-777?

Comment: It was the next available number.

Comment: @RaymondChen "Ecma International's TC39 is a group of JavaScript developers". It means there were 38 previous groups? I'm not sure... As well as ecma-262. Does it mean there were 261 specifications?

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi You might want to check other resources like https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ and https://www.ecma-international.org/technical-committees/

Comment: [1](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-1/), [2](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-2/), ..., [261](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-261/), ...

Comment: Oh, before reading your links, I thought ecma was an organization that only maintains the ecmascript spec. I did not know that ecmascript is a small part of a large standardization system. And TC39 is a group of people tasked with maintaining that specification (ecma-262).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before reading the comments under this question I though that [ECMA international](https://www.ecma-international.org/) was an organization that was responsible only for ECMAScript and nothing else. And all these numbers in this context were strange for me. But now, I understand that ECMA is an organization that standardizes things. And ECMAscript (alias for the ecma-262 specification) is one of those things.

Answering my question 262 means the next available number within ECMA organization to reference the specification, as well as -402. And 39 (in TC39) refers to a group of people who have been tasked with maintaining the ecma-262 specification. New group - new number, new standard - new number. Now it's clear.